# Grab data from every frame with Python API? without using bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame)

Tags: python, shape-keys, keyframes

Can you obtain data from multiple frames without using `bpy.context.scene.frame_set()`?
The above command takes too long on my scene, and I also have too many frames, but I only need to grab one numerical data from each frame.

Is there a way to do this without going to each frame or iteration? I'm specifically interested in grabbing Shape Key value from each frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the keyframe points of F-Curves directly, which doesn't require frame changes. Instead, the x-coordinate of a point is the time / keyframe, the y-coordinate is the value.

To find the right F-Curves, iterate over `Object.animation_data.action.fcurves` and check their `data_path` and `array_index` properties.

Related:
http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_quickstart.html#animation
(See the low level example)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was able to figure out where they are stored using your description and the link.
For my Shape Key in particular, the data were in 'D.actions[**action_num**].fcurves[**shape_key_num**].keyframe_points[**frame_num**].co[1]'